# How to set 4 space tab in bash

Tags: bash, space

It look like `set tabstop=4` in VIM, but I don't know how to set it in **bash**

for example:

```
echo -e "1234567890\t321\n1\t2\n123\t1"
```

current output:

```
1234567890      321
1       2
123     1
```

I want output like this:

```
1234567890  321
1   2
123 1
```

It can be shown in anywhere, just like `cat somefile` or `php -r 'echo "\t123";'`

How can I set tab width in bash?

Comment: It seems as if you can't change it (that's the answers I found). You could do spaces instead, but I guess you know that :p

Answer (score 84, accepted):

That's not a property of your shell (or php or cat). It's your terminal that manages the output.

Use the [`tabs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tabs.html) command to change the behavior:

```
$ tabs 4

$ echo -e "a\tb"      
a   b
$ tabs 12

$ echo -e "a\tb" 
a           b
```

(`tabs` is specified in POSIX, and output above is "faked": it's still a tab character between the two letters.)

Comment: A note: =tabs= is specified in **Unix** (POSIX with XSI option), not POSIX. Systems that conform to POSIX but not to Unix are not required to implement a =tabs= command.

Comment: Addition: Pager "less" is not affected, so use "less -x4"; For "git diff" use "git config --global core.pager 'less -x4'"

Comment: it doesn't effect vi editor on macOS terminal ssh Linux

Comment: @neckTwi: vi has its own settings

Comment: I know it's super old, but it's surprising to me that other programs like less and vim don't query the terminal about their tab stops before displaying the current file

Comment: @dlamblin How would one query the terminal for its tabs, please?

Answer (score 5):

`tabs 4` results in the following tabstop positions.  Which isn't quite what you asked for.

```
tab stop positions 4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
```

You asked for this..

```
tab stop positions 5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,57,61,65,69,73,77,80
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *  *
```

Specifying tabs with a single number creates an implicit list that starts from 0.
To create an explicit list such as what you asked for.  Provide a comma or space separated list of tab stop positions.
Like so: `tabs 5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,57,61,65,69,73,77`

See `man tabs` and `tabs -v` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an offset for the first tab (e.g. for `git diff`) you can use shell expansion to get stepped numbers:

```sh
tabs {5..300..4}
```

In the above, 5 is the first tab's width, the second number is your terminal width, the last is your regular tab width.

Answer (score 1):

You can set either regular or irregular intervals using the `tabs` utility. It will work whether you're doing your own output, using `cat` to output a file that already includes tabs or using the output of a program you don't control.

However, if you're controlling your output it's preferable to use `printf` instead of `echo` and format strings instead of tabs.

```
$ printf '%-12s%8.4f %-8s%6.2f\n' 'Some text' 23.456 'abc def' 11.22
Some text    23.4560 abc def  11.22
$ format='%*s%*.*f %*s%*.*f\n'
$ printf "$format" -12 'Some text' 8 4 23.456 -8 'abc def' 6 2 11.22
Some text    23.4560 abc def  11.22
```

Unless you want someone else to be able to control the output of your program using the `tabs` utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setterm to set this

```
setterm -regtabs 4
```

I put it in my .bash_profile but its not bash related specifically

Comment: setterm: terminal screen-256color does not support --regtabs

Comment: I got a similar result too: `setterm: terminal xterm does not support --regtabs`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

`~/.bash_profile`

```
# Set the tab stops
if [ -f ~/.bash_tab_stops ]; then
    . ~/.bash_tab_stops
fi
```

`~/.bash_tab_stops`

```
tab_width=4
terminal_width=$( stty size | awk '{print $2}' )

set_tab_stops() {
    local tab_width=$1 terminal_width=$2 tab_stops=''
    for (( i=1+$tab_width; $i<$terminal_width; i+=$tab_width )); do
        tab_stops+=$i','
    done
    tabs $tab_stops
}

set_tab_stops $tab_width $terminal_width
```

`GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
`PuTTY Release 0.73 Build platform: 64-bit x86 Windows`
`Linux VPS 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.centos.plus.x86_64`